# Inconsistent Nameless Column Handling Across Servers

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm running a very simple query across two different servers, on two different PHP versions, and getting inconsistent results. I can change my query to get consistent results, so I've figured out *what* went wrong, but I'd like some pointers on *why* this happened.

My query is a very simple `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '{$table}'`, then fetching the associative array with PDO. Works fine when there's a result. When there are no results found, however, the results are inconsistent.

On one server (PHP 7.4.24), I get the following result from print_r:

```
Array
{
    [0] => (int) 0
}
```

However, on the other server (PHP 7.4.6), I get the following result from the same query:

```
Array
{
    [computed] => (string) 0
}
```

They are not pulling from the same SQL Server, but one table is a copy of the other, so while a table difference wouldn't explain this, a database setting might. Exact same code, so there must be something weird on either the PHP version or some server configs.

Any idea what setting/extension/whatever could cause a difference like this?

Comment: Let's see your PHP code. I'd be more worried about the type change to `string` than the column name. Why don't you just name the column?

Comment: @Charlieface I did end up naming the column. I just wanted to know why this was happening. This is for my own learning, not looking for a solution. The code is literally just my select and then a pdo fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC).

Comment: In prod, staging, dev all servers, data is being returned as an object in the json response. but when I look into my local, I see it's sent as a string in json. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯